# MailItem_PropertyChange event is firing three times when recipient is changed

Tags: vba, outlook, eventhandler, mailitem

I am trying to automatically fill the salutation in my mails depending on the recipient.

To start this routine I use the event MailItem_PropertyChange which is gives back the name of the changed property.

At any change of the "To" field the event handler fires three times.
The first time it gives back the name "To".
The second time it gives back the name "CC".
The third time it gives back the name "BCC".

This means, no matter which one of the three values I change, my routine always acts as if I changed the To value.

```vb
Private Sub objMail_PropertyChange(ByVal Name As String)
    If Name = "To" Then
        objMail.htmlBody = "Hallo Zusammen" & objMail.htmlBody
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because 3 properties (potentially) change.

[image]

Comment: Sure but the important word is "potentially". Using this event handler you will always get back the three names. What use is in giving back the names of three values when only one has been changed and how can I make sure, that the wanted action will only be taken, when the To value (for example) has been changed?

Comment: BTW where does this screenshot come from?

Comment: Outlook stores all recipients (To/CC/BCC) in a single collection (`MailItem,.Recipients`), so a change there can potentially mean a change in any or all of the 3 properties. 
The screenshot is from OutlookSpy (https://www.dimastr.com/outspy)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. So I will have to go on looking for a workaround.